# IF statement construction

Tags: r, excel

In excel you can create a new_column and define it to have a value 0 if the old_column is blank, and be 1 if old_column is not blank.

```
new_column=IF(ISBLANK([@[old_column]]),0,1)
```

Anyone can think of an efficient way to do this for a data frame in r. Say a column in the data frame is called old_column, I want to add a new_column to the data_frame with the above description.

I tried this:

```
mydf$old_column[is.na(mydf$old_column] <- 0
mydf$old_column[!is.na(mydf$old_column] <- 1
```

but it gives me this error:

> invalid factor level, NA generated error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mydf$new_column <- as.integer(!is.na(mydf$old_column)
```

You may not even need the `as.integer()` as `is.na()` returns a boolean vector and R treats `TRUE` and `FALSE` as `1` and `0` respectively.

Comment: Might be safer (and more efficient) to use `as.integer` instead

Comment: So changed. Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean with the negation: `!is.na(...)`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to follow the same scheme than in excel, then you are looking for ifelse:

```
mydf$new_column <- ifelse(is.na(mydf$old_column),0,1)
```

Also, in your original code, note that you assign the value to the old_column, so the second command will not find any NA's and will assign 1 everywhere.

The factor problem (guessing here), can be related to how you have loaded the data from your csv or xls file into R. Many methods have a parameter stringsAsFactors that you may want to set to False otherwise you can run into this type of errors. Provide the code, and we can help you. Example:

```
mydf <- read.csv("myfile.csv",stringsAsFactors = F)
```